# SVN ignoring .aux, .log, .gz and .pdf when typesetting version controlled .tex files

Tags: svn, latex

Suppose I have a project that uses SVN for version control and includes .tex files.  Collaborators may wish to typeset/compile these .tex files into .pdf files in order to view how they look.  This has a side effect of creating the .aux, .log, .gz, and of course the .pdf file in the directory of the .tex file.  Since these are redundant, is it possible to tell SVN to ignore those file extensions when running a command like "svn status?"  That way the repo only has .tex files in it and does not waste space on those additional files.

I found this question, which I believe asks the more or less the same thing as mine:

(1) [SVN Update specific files from repository only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003963/svn-update-specific-files-from-repository-only)

My issue with it, is that it seems like a lot of work for a little feature.  Basically if SVN could just be told

"hey, these files are actually semantically irrelevant/vacuous/redundant for the project.  You don't need to add them or put them under version control!," *that would be great*.

Answer (score 0):

You want the command

```
svn propedit svn:ignore directory_name
```

Details here:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html

You can set the repository to ignore certain files, this will stop them showing up when checking out/committing.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to incorporate this automatically; i.e. so if a new collaborator joins the project and checks it out, they don't need to run this command?

Comment: That's how it's designed to work. You'll be changing the repository, it's not a per-user setting.

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't think "svn ignore" is a command, though your link is correct. You want to set the svn:ignore property on the containing directory; for that the command is `svn propedit svn:ignore directory_name` or some use of `svn propset`